# No "Tests" Tab in TeamCity Build Log after Selenium GUI Tests Execution with Nunit 3.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, nunit, teamcity

We are executing our Selenium WebDriver GUI tests as a Nunit 3.0 build step in TeamCity 10 and after going through the documentation, we were expecting to see the test execution log in a separate "Tests" tab in the build log. However, there is no "Tests" tab at all in our log and the nunit.xml file with the results is saved only as an artifact in the tmp folder.
Have you come into the same issue? Could you please assist us?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The tests results should be somehow reported into TeamCity. Test can reported by build runner (see the list of the [supported frameworks](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Testing+Frameworks)), using [XML Report processing](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/XML+Report+Processing) build feature or via [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests). In your case you can use XML report processing feature to parse nunit.xml and report test in TeamCity.

Comment: Using service messages I cannot get the tests tab to show up. Could you please take a look at  my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810424/teamcity-tests-tab-wont-show-up-for-custom-testing-framework