# TeamCity tests tab won't show up for custom testing framework

Tags: python, teamcity

Many similar questions already exist but all address specific testing frameworks such as PHP or Junit. I would like to get the tests tab to appear using a custom framework that makes use of service messages along the lines of

```
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name = 'Benchmark.Tests']
```

To do its work. Do I still need XML report processing to do this or is there an easier way? My 'tests' are simply checked out of a testing directory, each containing test subdirectories and a little python script for each test. The script outputs service messages to indicate whether the test has succeeded or failed.

How do I get the tests tab to show up for this kind of setup?

Comment: Somebody please help with this. I'm really stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of you that encounter this problem. This is how I fixed it

The service messages are no joke, they do get the test tab to show up, but for this the following order is needed:

```
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name = 'tests'] 
##teamcity[testStarted name='tests.test1']
##teamcity[testFailed name ='tests.test1' message = 'error'] ---->> OPTIONAL!!!!
##teamcity[testFinished name ='tests.test1']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished name = 'tests']
```

Please note that the third service message is **OPTIONAL** whereas all the others are **REQUIRED**. The third service message should only show up for failed tests. For successful tests only three services messages should occur (ie testSuiteStarted, testStarted, testFinished and testSuiteFinished).

In the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) they should really make this a lot clearer. They are presenting a huge list of possible service messages without really specifying which are required and which are optional...